# git flow feature name isn't what it seems

Tags: git, git-flow

I create a feature branch in git bash (windows) with `git flow feature start myname`.
I get the message:

`- A new branch 'feature/myname' was created, based on 'develop'
- You are now on branch 'feature/myname'`

but when I type `git branch [tab][tab]` the name of the feature is FEATURE/myname. Why is the feature part uppercased and what can I do to fix it it?

Comment: Does `git branch` also show the uppercased `feature` part?

Comment: Yes, `git branch` shows it uppercased. It seems that git flow prefixes the branch with FEATURE but the problem is that it doesn't show in the console so that when I for example run push the feature the branch is not found - I have to set the upstream to FEATURE/myname.

Comment: What's the output of `git config --get gitflow.prefix.feature`?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below steps.

Go to your project folder.
Type "git flow init -f", It will ask you the below details.

```
Which branch should be used for bringing forth production releases?
- develop
- master
Branch name for production releases: [master]

Which branch should be used for integration of the "next release"?
- develop
Branch name for "next release" development: [develop]

How to name your supporting branch prefixes?
Feature branches? [FEATURE/] 
Bugfix branches? [bugfix/] 
Release branches? [release/] 
Hotfix branches? [hotfix/] 
Support branches? [support/] 
Version tag prefix? [v]
```

For "Feature branches? [FEATURE/]" type feature.